# Memcached - doesn't seem to be working

Tags: cache, memcached, magento

my local.xml

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<cache>
  <backend>memcached</backend>
  <prefix>MAGE_</prefix>
  <memcached>
    <servers>
      <server>
        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
        <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
        <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </memcached>
</cache>
```

/var/cache is still filling up

memachced is running

```
memcache 2685 0.0 0.3 351888 26152 ? Sl 08:07 0:19 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
```

How do i know its working? I notice no speed increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache won't improve performance unless you had severe I/OWait issues to begin with. You'll see an improvement with artificial performance tests like Siege / MagePerfTest for concurrency, but otherwise, no discernable difference to overall page load time.

`./var/cache` will continue to fill up with cache tags (not cache data), see https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/what-is-memcache-actually-caching-in-magento/

You can force caching without tags by setting the slow back end to memcache, see https://help.sonassihosting.com/secure-advanced-shared/using-memcache/

Just change the socket information to tcp/ip

Memcached

Memcached

memcached

Answer (score 0):

Try to look memcache stats on server with command

```
echo stats | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Comment: How can I see from stats if memcache is actually caching something?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to check if your server is working as expected. One solution is, that you use a control panel to see the plain stored data. This can also help You with debugging your future application.

http://livebookmark.net/journal/2008/05/21/memcachephp-stats-like-apcphp/